# Bloch sphere - qubit representation with application of Pauli Matrices

Tags: mathematical-physics, spherical-coordinates, quantum-computation

Consider the qubit $|\psi\rangle$ in it's canonical form:
$$
|\psi\rangle = \cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle
$$
associated with the point $\big(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\cos(\theta)\big)$ in Bloch's sphere. What are the points associated with the qubits:
$$
X|\psi\rangle\text{ , }Y|\psi\rangle\text{ , }Z|\psi\rangle
$$
where X, Y and Z are pauli matrices.

---

How am I able to do that? I know how Pauli matrices change the basis qubits... For example, $X$ applications changes $|0\rangle \longrightarrow |1\rangle$ and $|1\rangle \longrightarrow |0\rangle$. But after applying X, Y and Z, I just don't know how to interpret its coefficients as coordinates in Bloch sphere.

Can someone please help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, we compute
$$
X |\psi\rangle = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}[\cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle]\\
= \cos(\theta/2)|1\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|0\rangle
\\ = e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|0\rangle + \cos(\theta/2)|1\rangle
$$
However, this state is not in the required canonical form since the coefficient of $|0\rangle$ has a non-zero complex phase.  So, we multiply the entire vector by an appropriate complex phase (which is to say we divide the whole vector by $e^{i\phi}$) to get
$$
\sin(\theta/2)|0\rangle + e^{-i\phi}\cos(\theta/2)|1\rangle
$$
Now, in order to convert this vector into Bloch-coordinates, we need to write this in the canonical form of
$$
\cos(\hat \theta/2) |0\rangle + e^{i\hat \phi} \sin(\hat \theta/2) | 1 \rangle
$$
for angles $\hat \theta, \hat \phi$.  We associate this with the point $\big(\sin(\hat \theta)\cos(\hat\phi),\sin(\hat \theta)\sin(\hat \phi),\cos(\hat \theta)\big)$.  To that end, we note that
$$
\sin (\theta/2) = \cos((\pi - \theta)/2),\\
\cos (\theta/2) = \sin((\pi - \theta)/2),\\
e^{-i\phi} = e^{i(2\pi  - \phi)}
$$
And with this association, we can write
$$
e^{-i\phi} X | \psi \rangle = \cos(\hat \theta/2) |0\rangle + e^{i\hat \phi} \sin(\hat \theta/2) | 1 \rangle
$$
where $\hat \theta = \pi - \theta$ and $\hat\phi = (2 \pi - \phi)$.